# Implications for removing a public IP address from VM hosted in Azure

Tags: virtual-machines, azure

Through a general audit of our Azure environment, we found two VM's in our production system that have public IP's assigned.  The Network Security Groups had already been configured to be very restrictive (limited to just inbound from an existing VNET), but I'd still like to remove the public IP address since we don't need it.

As mentioned, these are currently running production VM's and I'd like to remove the IP ASAP.  Will removing the public IP address from the NIC cause any interruptions on the VM?  I doubt it would need a reboot or anything, I just want to make sure I'm causing little to no disruption in the network traffic (this VM is hosting a database).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your NSG is already restricted to azure Vnets then removing the Public IP should have no impact on the VM's.

remember that the RDP from external is also done via the Public IP unless you have a site to site VPN you might be locked out of RDP admin.

I have done this a few times and did not notice any issues. 
but to be safe i would also do it at a low period of network activity as the Virtual NIC might restart during the process.

Answer (score 1):

First, ensure you have no Apps or services using the Public IP address on your VM.
Since your NSG has configured to block all public traffic, **there is no impact on your VM if you dissociate the Public IP address from it**. Because the public IP address is associated to the NIC of the VM. After dissociating the PIP, the VM won't restart.

If you still want to RDP to the VM after removing the Public IP, you can choose many ways to achieve that, such as RDP it from another VM in the same VNet, Create a VPN gateway and RDP it from private IP address and etc.

Also, I did a test and found that **the NIC would not restart** when you dissociate the Public IP from it.You can still connect the VM from the private IP address.

Comment: As it turns out, we need the public IP address for a third-party integration that does IP whitelisting so it will have to stay for now.  Thanks for the details!